# Create Slanted Div with just border , no background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to create a slanted div and i have gone through many of the available content on internet but not getting the expected result.
I have attached the image([slanted Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihSlK.png)) for expected slanted div. I want div to be look slanted using border but not using background color. In case of border one of the edge is not visible. Please, let me know how i can achieve it.
[new Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4aFI.jpg) (Attached Image for slanted div)

```css
#slanted_div{ 
 position: relative; 
 display: inline-block; 
 padding: 1em 5em 1em 1em; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 color: #08393A; 
}
#slanted_div:before{ 
 content: ''; 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
 border:1px #08393A; 
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0; 
 -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0; 
 transform-origin: 100% 0; 
 -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg); 
 -ms-transform: skew(-45deg); 
 transform: skew(-45deg); 
 z-index: -1; 
 border-style: solid; 
}
```

```html
<div id="slanted_div"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far (https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: #slanted_div{
 position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 5em 1em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #08393A;
}

#slanted_div:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  border:1px #08393A;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
  border-style: solid;
}

Comment: In your post formatted correctly and not in comments please

Comment: @zer00ne  i have attached the code

Comment: Why are you using a :before, if you want a slanted div, then why are you not just slanting the div?.  eg. just doing this will slant a div. -> `#slanted_div{ width: 200px; height: 200px; border:5px solid #08393A; transform: skew(-45deg); }`

Comment: @vikassrivastava Did you want the border like the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihSlK.png)? It looks more like a broken or jagged line than a true slant.

Comment: @zer00ne i have attached image liked that div i wants to create.

Comment: The new image is nothing like the old image

Comment: I uploaded that to have the clear view of the image because last one was created using paint . In the new image lines are clear and they are not broken .

Answer (score 0):

check if you can set fixed width and height to your #slanted_div and add an ::after selector to use it as bottom-left borders while ::before remains setting up and right borders. Leave you here a example of what I mean:

```css
#slanted_div{ 
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
#slanted_div::before{ 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px rgb(8, 57, 58) solid;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
#slanted_div::after{ 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 202px;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px rgb(8, 57, 58) solid;
  border-left: 1px rgb(8, 57, 58) solid;
  border-right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="slanted_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Staranco . could you please , let me know how i can create the the second image

Comment: If my previous answer was ok for you, at least you could vote it and not just ask for more solutions

Comment: Hi @Staranco - Really thanks a lots for all your answers , and i tried to vote you at first day but my reputation is below 15 so it's recorded but will not be displayed publicly. Now i am able to design all kind of slanted div .Once again thanks and i'll vote everyone who ever helped me once i have enough reputation :) .

Comment: Glad to hear that you can do it now! :) Cheers